# Windows API Beep Function in NASM Assembly

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to work with the Windows API in NASM assembly, just some basic calling of functions and whatnot. So, I went to the MSDN website and read about the Beep function. It said that it takes two values, both double words, frequency and duration. So this is what my assembly program looks like:

```
NULL equ 0 ; null
global _start ; entry point
extern Beep, ExitProcess ; the stuff I need

section .data
    beepfreq dd 37 ; limit of 37 to 32,767
    beepdur dd 300 ; This is in milliseconds

section .bss
    dummy resd 1 ; nothing

section .text
_start:
    push beepfreq ; beep frequency
    push beepdur ; beep duration
    call Beep ; call it

    push NULL
    call ExitProcess
```

However, when I run the program the beep always sounds the same, and it lasts a lot longer than 300 milliseconds. No matter what I change the frequency or duration to, it always sounds the same. Why?

Comment: On what Windows version are you calling this function?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit Home edition.

Comment: You push call arguments to stack in wrong order.

Comment: It is the same result either way. Is it always backwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
push beepfreq ; beep frequency
push beepdur ; beep duration
call Beep ; call it
```

should be:

```
push dword [beepdur] 
push dword [beepfreq] 
call Beep ; call it
```

First; parameters are pushed right-to-left (i.e. the first parameter to the function should be pushed last).
Secondly; in NASM syntax `push beepfreq` means "`push` the address of `beepfreq`" (like `push OFFSET beepfreq` in MASM/TASM syntax). To get the value at that address you use brackets.

Comment: This works! Thanks! Although I had to add dword before [beepfreq] and [beepdur]

Comment: I thought NASM would've been able to deduce the size, but I guess not. I've updated my answer.